# How to prevent SIGPIPE in multi-thread program?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I wrote a tiny httpd. But if I send many request to httpd in a short period of time, httpd will exit because of SIGPIPE.

After searching on Google, I add

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
sigset_t signal_mask; 
sigemptyset(&signal_mask); 
sigaddset(&signal_mask, SIGPIPE); 
if(pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signal_mask, NULL) == -1) 
perror("SIGPIPE");
```

and

```
send(fd, buf, strlen(buf), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

in my code to prevent SIGPIPE.

But httpd still exit because of SIGPIPE.

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

my code:

[httpd.c](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9fxR8YB9CT/)

[threadpool.c](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DxNHPXyMm7/)

Comment: Have you tried debugging using `gdb`?  You can manually disable `SIGPIPE` with `gdb handle SIGPIPE nostop`.

Comment: You have attempted to do the same in multiple ways (ignore SIGPIPE, block SIGPIPE, *and* tell `send` to ignore SIGPIPE) So it should *really* work ;-) Are you sure the program exits because of SIGPIPE and not due to some other problem? How did you determine SIGPIPE is the cause for exit?

Comment: Have your rebuilt your application after making this change?

Comment: `send` may do only a partial send and your code cannot handle that because it does not check the return value of `send` calls.

Comment: You should also post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is just ignore SIGPIPE (`signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` -- which you say you've done), and then *CAREFULLY* check *EVERY* write and send call to ensure you are checking the return value properly and dealing with any EPIPE (or other) errors you get.

The danger of ignoring SIGPIPE is that it's easy to get a program that runs off writing to a closed connection, ignoring errors, and never terminates.

Once you ignore SIGPIPE, your program will never exit due to a SIGPIPE.

Comment: I use `gcc -g httpd.c -lphtread` to compile my code, and use `strace -i ./httpd` to trace my program and it was killed by SIGPIPE. But the new program is `a.out`. So I was stracing the old program. Σ(っ°Д°;)っ.  When strace the correct program, It prevent SIGPIPE successfully.